# Case expression with Boolean from PostgreSQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I am translating a query from PostgreSQL to SQL Server. I didn't write the query in PostgreSQL and it's quite complicated for my knowledge so i don't understand every piece of it.

From my understand: we are trying to find the max version from p_policy and when insurancestatus = 7 or 14 / transactiontype = CAN, we compare two dates (whose format are BIG INT).

This is the PG Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BLABLABLA 
WHERE
pol.vnumber =  (
                  SELECT MAX(pol1.vnumber)
                  FROM p_policy pol1
                  AND ( CASE WHEN   pol1.insurancestatus IN (7,14)  
                                 or pol1.transactiontype IN ('CAN')
                                -- ('CAN','RCA')
                             THEN pol1.veffectivedate = pol1.vexpirydate
                             ELSE pol1.veffectivedate <> pol1.vexpirydate
                             END
                       )
AND pol1.vrecordstatus NOT IN (30,254) 
etc.
```

1. I am used to have a where statement where I compare it to a value. I understand here from the Case statement we will have a boolean, but still that must be compared to something?
2. Anyway the main purpose is to make it work in SQL, but I believe SQL can't read a CASE statement where THEN is a comparison.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BLABLABLA 
WHERE pol.vnumber =  
            (
              SELECT MAX(pol1.vnumber)
              FROM p_policy pol1
            
              WHERE sbuid = 4019
              

              AND ( CASE WHEN   pol1.insurancestatus IN (7,14)  
                             or pol1.transactiontype IN ('CAN')
                         THEN   CASE  
                                    WHEN pol1.veffectivedate = pol1.vexpirydate THEN 1
                                    WHEN pol1.veffectivedate <> pol1.vexpirydate THEN 0
                                 END
                    END
                   )

AND pol1.vrecordstatus NOT IN (30,254) 
etc.
```

And then I get this error from SQL Server (which directly the last line of the current code - so after the double case statement)

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 55
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

Thank you !Let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want boolean logic. The `CASE` expression would translate as:

```
(
    (
        (pol1.insurancestatus IN (7,14) OR  pol1.transactiontype = 'CAN')
        AND pol1.veffectivedate = pol1.vexpirydate
    ) OR (
        NOT (pol1.insurancestatus IN (7,14) OR pol1.transactiontype = 'CAN')
        AND pol1.veffectivedate <> pol1.vexpirydate
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main issues with your snippet, SQL Server-syntax-wise.

```sql
SELECT * FROM BLABLABLA WHERE 
        pol.vnumber =  /* PROBLEM 1: we haven't defined pol yet; SQL Server has no idea what pol.vnumber is here, so you're going to get an error when you resolve your boolean issue */
        (
          SELECT MAX(pol1.vnumber)
          FROM p_policy pol1
        
          WHERE sbuid = 4019
          

         AND ( CASE WHEN   pol1.insurancestatus IN (7,14)  
                         or pol1.transactiontype IN ('CAN')
                     THEN   CASE  
                                WHEN pol1.veffectivedate = pol1.vexpirydate THEN 1
                                WHEN pol1.veffectivedate <> pol1.vexpirydate THEN 0
                             END
                END
               ) /* PROBLEM 2: Your case statement returns a 1 or a 0.. 
                              which means your WHERE is saying 
                              WHERE sbuid = 4019 
                                AND (1) 
                                AND pol1.vrecordstatus NOT IN (30,254) 

                    SQL Doesn't like that. I think you meant to add a boolean operation using your 1 or 0 after the parenthesis. 
                    like this: */
                = 1

          AND pol1.vrecordstatus NOT IN (30,254)
```